# JavaScript array of objects returns length of zero during page load, but not in console?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, safari

I'm working on the following page:

http://www.waisman.wisc.edu/

Problem code (which is inline and can be found on line 848 of the page):

```
<script>
        var listType = "Basic",
            theList92 = document.querySelector('#block-92 > ol'),
            finalEventsList92 = "",
            futureEvents92 = [],
            pastEvents92 = [],
            nonWiley92 = [],
            events92 = [{
                title: "Golf Benefit 2015",
                date: new Date("2015, 7, 20"),
                time: "10:30 am",
                series: "Friends of the Waisman Center",
                speaker: "",
                thumbnail: "/images/Golf/GolfPhoto75x100.jpg",
                location: "Bishops Bay Country Club", url: "/events2015-GolfBenefit.htm"
            },{
                title: "David Stokes",
                date: new Date("2015, 5, 10"),
                time: "1 pm",
                series: "Children's Theatre",
                speaker: "David Stokes",
                thumbnail: "/images/CT/StokesDavidPuppets75x100.jpg",
                location: "Friends of the Waisman Center Auditorium", url: "/events-ctS2015-Stokes.htm"
            },{
                title: "&quot;The Genetics of Cerebellar Development and Function&quot;",
                date: new Date("2015, 4, 24"),
                time: "Noon",
                series: "John D. Wiley Seminar Series",
                speaker: "Dan Goldowitz, PhD",
                thumbnail: "/images/Seminars/GoldowitzDan75x100.jpg",
                location: "John D. Wiley Conference Center", url: "/seminars-2015-Apr24-Goldowitz.htm"
            },{
                title: "&quot;The Infant Brain Imaging Study (IBIS): Insights into the Early Development of Autism&quot;",
                date: new Date("2015, 4, 17"),
                time: "Noon",
                series: "John D. Wiley Seminar Series",
                speaker: "Joseph Piven, MD",
                thumbnail: "/images/Seminars/PivenJoe75x100.jpg",
                location: "John D. Wiley Conference Center", url: "/seminars-2015-Apr17-Piven.htm"
            },{
                title: "Snow White",
                date: new Date("2015, 4, 12"),
                time: "1 pm",
                series: "Children's Theatre",
                speaker: "PlayTime Productions",
                thumbnail: "/images/CT/PlaytimeBanner75x100.jpg",
                location: "Friends of the Waisman Center Auditorium", url: "/events-ctS2015-SnowWhite.htm"
            },{
                title: "&quot;Synaptic and Circuitry Mechanisms of Psychiatric Disorders&quot;",
                date: new Date("2015, 4, 10"),
                time: "Noon",
                series: "John D. Wiley Seminar Series",
                speaker: "Guoping Feng, PhD",
                thumbnail: "/images/Seminars/FengGuoping75x100.jpg",
                location: "John D. Wiley Conference Center", url: "/seminars-2015-Apr10-Feng.htm"
            },{}];

        events92.pop();

        if(events92.length === 0){

            finalEventsList92 = "<li>No matching events listed at this time.</li>";

        } else {
            if("Yes" === "Yes"){
                events92.forEach(function(wcEvent, index, array){
                    if(wcEvent.series !== "John D. Wiley Seminar Series"){
                        nonWiley92.push(wcEvent);
                    }
                });
                events92 = nonWiley92.reverse();
            }

            if("Future" === "Future"){
                events92.forEach(function(wcEvent, index, array){
                    if(wcEvent.date >= Date.now()){
                        futureEvents92.push(wcEvent);
                    }
                });

                futureEvents92.reverse();

                if(futureEvents92.length === 0){
                    finalEventsList92 = "<li>No matching events listed at this time.</li>";
                } else {        
                    futureEvents92.reverse();

                    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                        if(futureEvents92[i]){
                            if(listType === "Basic"){
                                finalEventsList92 += buildBasicListItem(futureEvents92[i]);
                            } else {
                                finalEventsList92 += buildListItemWithImage(futureEvents92[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if("Future" === "Past"){
                events92.forEach(function(wcEvent, index, array){
                    if(wcEvent.date < Date.now()){
                        pastEvents92.push(wcEvent);
                    }
                });
                if(pastEvents92.length === 0){
                    finalEventsList92 = "<li>No matching events listed at this time.</li>";
                } else {       
                    pastEvents92.reverse();

                    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                        if(pastEvents92[i]){
                            if(listType === "Basic"){
                                finalEventsList92 += buildBasicListItem(pastEvents92[i]);
                            } else {
                                finalEventsList92 += buildListItemWithImage(pastEvents92[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if("Future" === "All"){
                for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
                    if(events92[i]){
                        if(listType === "Basic"){
                            finalEventsList92 += buildBasicListItem(events92[i]);
                        } else {
                            finalEventsList92 += buildListItemWithImage(events92[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }    
        }

        theList92.innerHTML = finalEventsList92;

    </script>
```

In all browsers where it initial evaluated `events92.length === 0`, in the console, running the same command actually gives a correct length (66 in this case).

Also, I know there are some odd looking comparisons (like `"Future" === "Future"`, but the list is being generated by a CMS and this is how we allow users to adjust the display of the lists as the CMS is not dynamic like a WordPress.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you wait until the page is finished rendering before you counted the objects?

Comment: I'm guessing you try to get the objects before the DOM is fully loaded, which will return .length of 0.

Comment: @PaulTomblin The objects are counted immediately after the object is created. If you use the inspector you can see the script tag that is creating the collection. I'll add the code to the original post.

Comment: @JamesG. I've added code. The code I added is inline (blocking) JS so I'm not sure why it would not get the proper length of an object that I created right before doing the comparison.

Comment: It works exactly like you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/uo7nq1pn/ There is something else going on here that isn't in here. And as a side note, a CMS generating JS seems like a bad idea. The CMS should churn out JSON data which static unchanging JS then consumes.

Comment: @AlexWayne, I figured it out, see my answer. The date format was incorrect and IE/Safari couldn't parse it properly. Why that would impact the array.length property I'm not sure, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out.

I was using the following:

`new Date("2014, 01, 01")` which IE and Safari won't parse properly. I just removed the quotes, and everything appears to be working properly.

The odd thing is that it will NOT throw an error in the console, but when you look the objects it will say "Invalid Date".

I'm also not sure why this would impact the array.length property, but it does (at least in IE/Safari).

So for those that maybe using the same format, just remove the quotes:

`new Date(2014, 01, 01)`